# How to add Search function with reactjs in with api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on react app which uses redux for state management. In this app i have to implement search page. In which when user types on search box the app display the product related to that text input.
I have api endpoint like this `api.XXXXXXX.com/buyer/product/filter?q=${inputValue}`. I tried implement this but i am not able filter this. I haven't worked on this before and couldn't find good tutorial for this.

> Here is my code
>
> searchAction.js

```
export const searchProduct =(value) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: searchActionTypes.SEARCH_PRODUCT_LOAD
  });
  new _rest().get(`/buyer/product/filter?q=${value}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        dispatch({
          type: searchActionTypes.SEARCH_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
          payload: res
        })
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        dispatch({
          type: searchActionTypes.SEARCH_PRODUCT_ERROR,
          error: err
        })
  });
}
```

> searchActionreducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    isFetching: false,
    searchData: {},
    isFetched: false,
    isError: null
}

export default (state=initialState, action) =>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case searchActionTypes.SEARCH_PRODUCT_LOAD:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true
            };
        case searchActionTypes.SEARCH_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                searchData: action.payload.data._embedded,
                isFetched: true
            };
        case searchActionTypes.SEARCH_PRODUCT_ERROR:
            return  {
                ...state,
                isFetched: false,
            };
        default:
            return  {
                ...state
            }
    }
}
```

> searchPage.js

```
class SearchPage extends  React.Component {
    state = {
        inputValue: '',
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.searchProduct('');
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        console.log('component update', prevState)
        if(this.state.inputValue !== prevState.inputValue) {
            this.props.searchProduct(this.state.inputValue);
        }
    }


    render() {
        console.log('SearchPage Result', this.props.product);
        const {product} = this.props;
        const {inputValue} =this.state;

        const updateInputValue = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.setState({
                inputValue: e.target.value
            })
        }
        return(
            <Grid container>
            <div style={{width: '100%', display:'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <form  noValidate autoComplete="off">
                    <TextField value={inputValue} onChange={updateInputValue} id="standard-basic" label="Search Product" />
                </form>
            </div>
                <Grid container spacing={8} style={{padding: '30px'}}>
                    {product && product.productResourceList &&
                    product.productResourceList.map((data, index) => {
                        return(
                            <Grid item xs={6}>
                            <MainCards key={data.productId} data={data} />
                            </Grid>
                        )
                    })}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps =(state) => {
    return {

        product: state.search.searchData
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    searchProduct,

}
export default  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchPage);
```

Here In `componentDidMount` Initially when component mounts i made display all the product. After that in `componentDidUpdate` i trying get filtered data from api buy passing `this.state.inputValue` as value of `q` in api endpoint `api.XXXXXXX.com/buyer/product/filter?q=${inputValue}`. But component is not updating at all.

Comment: What do you get back from the api when you call `searchProduct` in `componentDidUpdate`? Is it the same data? Since you say it works for all products in `componentDidMount` it sounds like get handler is not filtering correctly.

Comment: I don't know how to check for this in componentDidUpdate. Actully this.props.searchProduct action in takes data from and point and pass it to searcProduct state in reducer.

Comment: What does the `console.log(res)` in your `searchProduct` action say when it gets called with a non-empty string by `componentDidUpdate`?